# COGNOS gives error 'Column ambiguously defined'

Tags: cognos-8

When I try to run a report in COGNOS Report Studio, I get error : `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined`
Now there is no way to get the runtime sql and test it out against the oracle db. So I am left groping around. 
My question is...when we develop the model in framework manager, we do not write our own sql. Just specify the tables and columns and joins. So the error should never come because this error come when you forget to prefix a column name with the table alias.

Answer (score 0):

I agree it is odd. Start removing data items from the query until it works. Try to narrow it down to a specific data item within a table. See what SQL is generated without the offending field, that should give you a hint as to what is going on.